# wmplayer.ocx inconsistent behavior in powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, media-player

I tried this short script:

```
$wmp = new-object -com wmplayer.ocx
$wmp.url = "c:\temp\song.wav"
$wmp.controls.play()
```

On the 3 different environments below, it gives inconsistent behavior:

1. PowerShell ISE on Windows 7 x64: no sound
2. PowerShell on Windows 7 x64: produce sound
3. PowerShell on Windows 8 x64: no sound

Is there anything I should watch out?
Incidentally, if I use $wmp.openPlayer("c:\temp\song.wav"), it seems to work.